# Encoding Problems in 2019 Premiere, AfterEffects and Media Encoder

Tags: premiere, after-effects, encoding, adobe-media-encoder

I know this question was asked before, and I've read pretty much all of them and I have no solution to this. Until recently, I could render everything just fine but when I am rendering a 2 minute 1080p video, it is taking ridiculously long (see the image for details). Last time I checked, it was showing around 8 hours or so and it keeps increasing. I've tried encoding in Adobe Media Encoder 2019, Premiere and After Effects and the result is all the same. Normally it would take me only a couple of minutes to render such short video on my system.

- Ryzen 5 2600X 6 core CPU
- 32GB 3200mhz DDR4 memory
- RTX 2060 GPU
- All of the project files are on Samsung 970 evo plus M.2 drives
- I've tried encoding with CUDA supported and software only encoder
- I've tried different presets as well as my desired export settings and it's all the same
- All of my drivers are up to date (including GPU).

I'm about to lose my head because I have to deliver this within 3 days and now this is happening. Anyone experienced this before? Please help if you know anything about this, I'm desperate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had lots of weirdness with Dynamic Link recently with the latest versions of creative cloud 2019. 
Sometimes it goes really slowly when you have projects that include linked AE comps in Premiere. 
I would try exporting any comps from AE as proRes files, into premiere. Then exporting your videos directly in Premiere without using Media Encoder, and see if that makes it any quicker.